# Linear transformation and orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-transformations, orthonormal

A transformation $T: V\to W$ transform m-dimensional space $V$ to n-dimensional space $W$ is given by $n\times m$ matrix $M$, such that we map vector $x$ from $V$ to $W$ as follows:

$\mathbf{x}^i = \mathbf{M} \mathbf{x}$

My question is that what is $M$? is it the orthonormal basis of $W$.

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear. Are you asking what the columns or rows of the matrix $M$ would be? Also, is your definition of $M$ that it maps the basis elements of $V$ onto those of $W$? As a side note, any linearly independent set of $n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space is a basis so it does not make sense to discuss ``the" basis unless one has been previously specified or is understood (e.g. if $V=\mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Answer (score 0):

$M$ is the matrix corresponding to the linear transformation $T$, expressed in some (possibly orthonormal) bases for $V$ and $W$.